# how to convert rows to columns based on date column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

Here is SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25542/2/0

I just want to get my data as

```
Sale_On    | Count Refunded | Count Sale | Count Cashback
-------------------------------------------------------
2015-09-07 |   1            |    5       |     1
```

I read about the 'case-when' in MySQL but, in this case I have to write each order_status manually.

How can I do that? Any other solution rather than to convert rows to columns ?

Comment: It is strange to `RIGHT JOIN` beween `orders` and `order_detail`: if an `order_id` does not exist in `orders` but does exist in `order_detail`, surely it should be ignored in this query—i.e. you want an *inner* join (a left join could also be appropriate, if you want to include `order_id`s that exist in `orders` but not `order_detail`, though given there'd be no `order_status` in such cases, it won't make any difference).

Comment: yes, it should be inner join. I wrote right join by mistake.

Comment: [A more generic answer](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) to the "pivot" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy to hard-code the statuses, you could perform an aggregation over them:

```sql
SELECT   DATE(o.sale_on),
         SUM(od.order_status=1) AS Sales,
         SUM(od.order_status=2) AS Refunds,
         SUM(od.order_status=3) AS Cashbacks
FROM     orders o RIGHT JOIN order_detail od USING (order_id)
GROUP BY DATE(o.sale_on)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25542/12/0).

Otherwise you'd effectively need to generate similar SQL dynamically using a query on your `master_order_status` table to generate the respective columns in the select list.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the use of sum here? why can't I use count here?

Comment: @SunilGarg: [`COUNT(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) "*returns a count of the number of non-`NULL` values of **`expr`** in the rows retrieved by a `SELECT` statement*".  Since the boolean expressions `od.order_status=1` etc always evaluate to either 1 or 0, they are always non-`NULL`.  You want to add up those 1s instead, which is a [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Comment: can't we do it dynamically? Instead of mentioning each status manually , it should fetch it automatically  from master_order_status.

Comment: @SunilGarg: Isn't that what the final paragraph of my answer says?

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
select sale_on,
max(case when status='sale' then c end) as count_Sales,
max(case when status='Refunded' then c end) as count_Refunded,
max(case when status='CashBack' then c end) as count_CashBack
from
(
SELECT o.sale_on,od.order_status,COUNT(*) as c,mos.status FROM orders o
RIGHT JOIN order_detail od ON o.order_id = od.order_id
LEFT JOIN `master_order_status` mos ON mos.`status_id` = od.order_status
GROUP BY DATE(o.sale_on),od.order_status
  ) as t group by sale_on
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25542/13