# Rows to columns based on date/time in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Here is the part of the table:
[image]

I need to transform it to this:
[image]

I used aggregation but it fills with a lot of null cells. Of course there are more records with different timestamp in the table like : 09/02/2020 21:30:00 and so on..
I see similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437652/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-based-on-date-column) but I thing is somehow messed up in the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I tried but it failing to display it properly

Comment: Well this will cause, a bad reputation with no answers :(

Comment: Use [TABLE GENERATOR](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for formatting your table data. Simply paste your data using `File -> Paste table data`.It will create a table for you. We want it as a text because We can hardly see anything from the image you had posted

Comment: When you click on the image it will be better

Comment: @Arun Palanisamy I used TABLE GENERATOR in my question. But my data is too log to fit the margin of this website. So I made the images that are in good quallity after you click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using conditional aggregation.

```
select recordtime, 
       max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = 'FirstName') as "First Name",
       max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = 'SecondName') as "Second Name",
       max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = 'ThirdName') as "Third Name", 
       .... repeat for all possible full names ...
       max(qualitydesc) as "QualityDesc", 
       max(statedesc) as "StateDesc"
from the_table
group by recordtime
order by recordtime;
```

Comment: I thing its working. But what about for the time its messed up(not in correct order)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "time its messed up" - are you looking for an `order by`?

Comment: Yes that I meant, sorry

Comment: excuse me @a_horse_with_no_name can you see my new question related by your solution here, please. :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207632/conditional-aggregation-filter-in-laravel