# Conditional aggregation, filter in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pivot

This is my second question based after the solution of [Rows to columns based on date/time in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188541/rows-to-columns-based-on-date-time-in-postgresql)
The table is in the upper link :)

Here is my model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StambMeasCanal extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'stamb';
  protected $table = 'meas_kanal';
  protected $fillable = ['fullname','formattedvalue','recordtime','qualitydesc','statedesc','id'];
}
```

Part of my controller:

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
  $start_date = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
  $end_date = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');
  if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
  {
    // if user fill dates
    $dateScope = array($request->start_date ." 00:00:00", $request->end_date ." 23:59:59");
  } else {
    // default load page - today
    $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
  };

  $students = StambMeasCanal::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
  ->selectRaw('recordtime')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "Данни.Кота") as kotaiazovir')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "Данни.Напрежение") as naprevenieqzovir')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "Данни.Температура") as tempqzovir')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "Данни.Температура_табло") as temptabloqzovir')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "Данни.Ниво") as nivoqzovir')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_00_600.Данни.Напрежение") as naprevenie600')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_00_600.Данни.Ниво") as nivo600')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_00_600.Данни.НивоУЗ") as nivouz600')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_00_600.Данни.Разход") as razhod600')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_00_600.Данни.Температура") as temperatura600')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_09_200.Данни.Напрежение") as naprevenie200')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_09_200.Данни.Ниво") as nivo200')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_09_200.Данни.НивоУЗ") as nivouz200')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_09_200.Данни.Разход") as razhod200')
  ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = "ГСК_09_200.Данни.Температура") as temperatura200')
  ->selectRaw('max(qualitydesc) as QualityDesc')
  ->selectRaw('max(qualitydesc) as StateDesc')
  ->groupBy('recordtime')
  ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
  ->get();

  return Datatables::of($meascanal)
  ->make(true);
}
```

After the request i have an error:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "Данни.Кота" does not exist↵LINE 1: ...ime, max(formattedvalue)..
```

Is it beacouse bad integration that I made in the laravel query?

EDIT1:
The problem was the quotes. I needed to escape them:

```
where fullname = \'Данни.Кота\'
```

EDIT2:

The last two columns(QualityDesc and StateDesc) are not bound to any FormattedValue columns and are displayed in wrong order... Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide resulting query using `->toSql() ` method

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I have updated my question.